# Microsoft Graph Delta Query support to sync from “now”

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The differential query feature in AAD Graph allows for the following header:

```
ocp-aad-dq-include-only-delta-token: true
```

(Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query#AdditionalDifferentialQueryFeatures section "Differential Sync support to sync from now".)
Is there an equivalent feature (planned) for Microsoft Graph that allows me to "skip" to the end of delta stack without retrieving any data (this is the crucial part - token only)?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but this is high on our priority list.

Comment: Is there actually a roadmap page for Microsoft Graph? @dan-kershaw-msft

Comment: Any progress on this? It seems like an unnecessary load put on the api for clients that only need future changes. I have to make literally thousands of calls just to get to the final deltaToken url I need.